# "Pay with Amazon Express" error help in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I have integrated "`Pay with Amazon Express`" in my PHP Laravel Project It works fine in native PHP but in Laravel it shows following error :

> We're sorry, but there's a problem processing your payment from this
>   website.
>
> Your account has not been charged. Please contact seller for
>   assistance.

Can you help me that how can I debug it because I am unable to find what thing is causing error . Or what is causing this error?

I have used the following code https://github.com/amzn/pay-with-amazon-express-demo  and error snapshot is as follows: [screen shot of error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPv0j.png)

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/tuurbo/amazon-payment package?

Comment: No because its seems too complex for my scenario. I was trying to go with simple solution.